# Overly blurred image? Need to avoid processing already blurred portions of it

Tags: c++

I have this function semi-working, but it seems that the image that comes out is overly-blurred. this is because it is processing already blurred portions, I imagine?

I was told I need to write it to a new image, but I can't figure out how to create that. When I was using the Image tempImage constructor, I was getting errors of segmentation fault and could not determine why. Prior to this function, there is a function `scaleUp` that makes the image larger and save it to `newImage.pixelData`, created by the constructor  `Image newImage(width*numTimes, height*numTimes, colorMode);`

```
void Image::simpleBlur(int numPixels)
      {
           int middlePixX, middlePixY, redSum, greenSum, blueSum, denominator = 0;       

           //Image tempImage(width, height, colorMode);
           //tempImage.createImage(width, height);

           for (int middlePixX = 0; middlePixX < width; middlePixX++)
           {
              for (int middlePixY = 0; middlePixY < height; middlePixY++)
              {
                 for (int x_subgrid = -1*numPixels; x_subgrid <= numPixels; x_subgrid++) //for (int x_subgrid = 0;  x_subgrid < DIM_SQUARE; x_subgrid++)
                 {
                    for (int y_subgrid = -1*numPixels; y_subgrid <= numPixels; y_subgrid++) //for (int y_subgrid = 0; y_subgrid < DIM_SQUARE; y_subgrid++)
                    {
                        int xPos = x_subgrid + middlePixX;  
                        int yPos = y_subgrid + middlePixY;

                if( xPos >= 0 && xPos < width && yPos >= 0 && yPos < height ) 
                        {            
                          redSum = redSum + pixelData[xPos][yPos].getRed();
                          greenSum = greenSum + pixelData[xPos][yPos].getGreen();
                          blueSum = blueSum + pixelData[xPos][yPos].getBlue();
                          denominator++;
                       }
                    }
                 }
                 redSum = redSum / denominator; 
                 greenSum = greenSum / denominator;
                 blueSum = blueSum / denominator;
                 pixelData[middlePixX][middlePixY].setRed(redSum);
                 pixelData[middlePixX][middlePixY].setGreen(greenSum);
                 pixelData[middlePixX][middlePixY].setBlue(blueSum);

                 redSum, greenSum, blueSum = 0; denominator = 0;
              }
           }  
        }
```

Comment: What is an `Image`?  What were you doing to get a segfault?  My guess here would be that you're modifying the `Image` as you go along, so you need one of them to examine and another one to write to, so I'd like to know why it is that you can't create another one.  Finally, what's your question?

Comment: Image is a class.

I was using `Image tempImage(width, height, colorMode);` to create the new image (the blurred one) and trying to write to it, but it seemed to have been segfaulting in that call.

My question is, was that the correct step in the function, and something else was going wrong? Or is there a different want to create this 'temp' I am writing to

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your question a bit. Right now it's not clear whether you want to know about how to detect whether part of an image is blurry, or how to create a new image, or both, or perhaps something else. I doubt anybody can tell you about how to use the ctor of your `Image` class without having seen it...

Comment: What I must do:
scaleUp an image (make it larger, via `scaleUp` function - which I have and works). After this, `simpleBlur' is called. It  is to blur the image that is outputted of scaleUp.

Currently, the way it is written, the scaleUp output file is blurred, but as there is no 'temporary' buffer, simpleBlur seems to be blurring the original in process, making the final overly blurred.

Comment: Telling us what you have to do isn't the same as answering a question, particularly if you refuse to tell us vital information.  You need a temporary buffer without question.  You have said you had a segfault, which is almost completely useless information by itself.  It's also useless to simply tell us `Image` is a class, since we knew that already.  We can't help you without knowing more about your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do this operation in-place, but since it's a neighbourhood operation you'll get bizarre results. Ideally you need separate input and output images, or, if you really have to do this in-place, then you'll need a small temporary buffer (and slightly more complicated code) to prevent modified pixels being used in your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug in your algorithm, as you seem to suspect - as you blur pixel (x,y), it averages pixels above and directly to the left of it that have already been blurred, and you want to compute an average of the original contents. So you do need to process the old image to a new image somehow, or something similar.